# Why were *two* mods required to close this question?

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-close, moderators

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/117465/how-could-a-real-world-doomsday-cult-go-about-causing-the-apocalypse) is currently closed by Aify, Cadence, L.Dutch, Trish, and James (thank you for keeping the site clean). However, I'm confused because both L.Dutch and James are diamond moderators, and I'd always thought that the stereotypical "modhammer" meant that every mod had the ability to close each question on their own. Is this not the case? If not, when do mods modhammer questions open and closed?

Comment: I just posted a [follow-up question on the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316248/295232): are there any questions closed by 5 moderators?

Answer (score 13):

L.Dutch wasn't yet a moderator when they voted to close that question (on July 9th); they were only elected [on July 17th](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election/3), over one week later. Prior to that, they had normal 20k+ privileges, but not a binding close/reopen vote.

As an aside, the ability for a moderator to be able to cast a non-binding vote [has been a long-standing feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41062/274942), but it hasn't been implemented, and likely never will be.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the explanation! I didn't realize that diamonds were retroactively added to all instances of mods on the site.

Comment: There's a bit of a running joke about looking for a 5 mod closed question

Comment: @Dubukay Yeah, it's . . . a wee bit confusing, certainly. You're definitely not the first.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I want to say I've seen at least one question here where three mods closed it, but my memory is failing me as to which one in particular.

Comment: There are more than 20 of them; [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/905897) lists them all.